# Eagerly loading subtype specific entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, entity-framework-4

SubFoo is a subtype of Foo but only Bar displays the navigation property Bar. So

```
DB.Foos.Include('Bar')
```

generates

> A specified Include path is not valid. The EntityType 'Foo' does not declare a navigation property with the name 'Bar'.

What do I do? (besides obviously moving Bar to Foo)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way is to project

```
var q = from f in DB.Foos
        let b = (f as SubFoo).Bar
        select new
        {
            Foo = f,
            Bar = b
        };
 return q.AsEnumerable().Select(q => q.Foo);
```

Answer (score 1):

What about:

```
DB.Foos.OfType<SubFoo>().Include("Bar")
```

This doesn't work if you want general query over Foos (not only SubFoos) and all SubFoos must have Bar loaded..